# C scanf fails to correctly read char after a few

Tags: c, io, scanf

I might miss something really important but I cannot figure out and my teacher does not know either. I am reading char (y/n) as a console input answer, many times, (I do know about " %c" stuff.) I manage to read like 3-4 "y"-s but after that one fails, looks like a NULL and then manages the rest fine.

Functions: 
scanf for reading console
fprintf for writing to file

Even though I tried many ways, every time one of my variables fails to contain the real character. When I printf the struct element one by one it fails the same one every time. When I try to read that very one variable of the struct it prints corruptly the y answer. I will include code too, I input as:
address : asdf (whatever really)
size: 0
rest of them are y except the very last. I used to press 2020.

Actual reading:

```
    struct s_orders order;
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf(" %s", order.address);
    printf("Size of fields(m^2): ");
    scanf(" %d", &order.size);
    printf("Paint ordered?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &order.paint);
    printf("Revert ordered?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &order.revet);
    printf("Water-gas ordered?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &order.proba);
    printf("Kitchen creation ordered?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &order.uniq);
    printf("Uphol ordered?(y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &order.uphol);
    printf("Expiration date: ");
    scanf(" %s", order.date);
```

struct:

```
struct s_orders
{
    /* data */
    char address[100];
    int size;
    char paint;
    char revet;
    char proba;
    char water;
    char uniq;
    char uphol;
    char date[100];
};
```

Expected result: 
"asdf;0;y;y;y;y;y;y;2020;"

Gotten:
"asdf;0;y;y;y;(random char here);y;y;2020;"

Edit:
- I am simply bad at focusing, I forgot to ask for input for water variable. Thanks for help!

Comment: `%c` requires a `char *`, so you have to pass the address of your `char` variables.

Comment: Also, [Using fflush(stdin)](//stackoverflow.com/q/2979209)

Comment: I just tried my code with char[3] I left it wrong way, sorry, thanks

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for your help, improving my knowledge, ill remove it.

Comment: https://ibb.co/km1qP49 for me this is the output. As you can see I have two ; between the characters. Any suggestion why it is happening?

Comment: You have 6 fields, but only ask the user for 5. You never ask for `water` so it stays uninitialized.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am ashamed for making such a mistake.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: pretty sure you need to add a space after "%c ", &orderpaint like that

Comment: Johnny already answered it, I simply failed to request every each of variables. It does work now.